# mongodb: how to filter one document for each group with the same property value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, filter, mongoose

I have a mongodb collection structure like this one:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String,
  // ...
  alias: String
};
```

(I use mongoose, but this is secondary).

Since I fetch people from different sources, some of the documents can reference the same person: in this case I want to keep both people in database, and I assign them a (unique) alias to both of them.

Currently, when I need to make a query to list persons univocally, I retrieve all people, and then filter out aliases, keeping only one of them (I don't care which one), in javascript (of course I need to keep also persons with *no* alias).  Something like this:

```
Person.find({}, null, function(err, persons) {
  var result = [];
  var aliases = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
    if (persons[i].alias && aliases.hasOwnProperty(persons[i].alias))
      continue;  // skip this person because it's alias was seen already
    result.push(persons[i]); // add this person to result
    if (persons[i].alias) // add this person alias to seen aliases
      aliases[persons[i].alias] = true;
  }
});
```

Since this is quite slow, when people count grows, I'd like to filter out duplicated aliases (and keep just one) in the mongo query, but I can't elaborate a filter which fits...

Any clue?

**UPDATE**:
As requested i comment, I add some sample Person data:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "Alice" },
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "Bob",   "alias" : "afa776bea788cf4c" },
{ "_id" : "3", "name" : "Bobby", "alias" : "afa776bea788cf4c" },
{ "_id" : "4", "name" : "Zoe",   "alias" : "2211293acc82329a" },
```

From the query I'm looking for, I'd need to get:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "Alice" },
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "Bob",   "alias" : "afa776bea788cf4c" },
{ "_id" : "4", "name" : "Zoe",   "alias" : "2211293acc82329a" },
```

(getting "Bobby" instead of "Bob" would be fine too).

Of course this data structure is not mandatory, I'd accept a change suggestion, of course...

Comment: Can you please update the question with test data? This way its easier for people to test. Please add the input and the expected output as well.

Comment: Of course, sorry... Just added...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using aggregation you can use the following [$GROUP](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)query, to get the desired list:

> db.collection.aggregate([
>   {$group:{"_id":"$alias", "name":{$first:"$name"}, "id":{$first:"$_id"}}},
>   {$project:{"id":1,"_id":0,"alias":"$_id","name":1}}
>   ]);

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Model.distinct` operation.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct

```
Person.distinct('alias', callback);
```

This should return a list of documents that have distinct values for the alias.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using mongo aggregation.

As far as I understand there are documents without alias field. If it is incorrect you don't need first project operator.

```
Person.aggregate([
    {   $project: {
            alias: {$ifNull: ['$alias', "$_id"] },
            name: 1
        }
    },
    {   $group: { _id: "$alias", name: {$first: "$name"}}},
    {
        $project: {_id:0, name: 1}
    }
], callback);
```